# Stored Procedure Summation Of rows with same ID

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in which I get Data In between the desired months from user.

Q1. I want to show Membername instead of memberID. How do i get member name here from the member master table?

Q2. Secondly I want to add these rows(summation). Like each row stores a int value. I want the same rows with same member ID to add up and show me one single row for each type. 
for example if there are three entries for visitors in 3 months I dont want three separate rows display 1,1,1 instead I want a single row with value 3

```
USE [MTS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_MTS_MemberTracking_generateReport]    Script Date: 07-04-2015 14:48:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- sp_MTS_MemberTracking_generateReport '01/01/2015','03/01/2015'
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MTS_MemberTracking_generateReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@monthYearFrom datetime , @monthYearTo datetime 
AS

select MemberId,TrackingId,MonthYear, AttendanceInFormalMixer,AttendanceInFbb,GoodKarmaCredit,CupOfCofee,Business,Training,Visitors
from [dbo].[MTS_MemberTracking] MtsTracking
where MtsTracking.MonthYear >= @monthYearFrom and  MtsTracking.MonthYear <= @monthYearTo
```

Comment: read about join and aggregation functions

Comment: Ok... Will surely do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through your code and web page. you need something like this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MTS_MemberTracking_generateReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@monthYearFrom datetime , @monthYearTo datetime 
AS

    select max(mtsmem.Name) Name,MtsTracking.MemberId,--TrackingId,MonthYear,
     sum(Convert(int,AttendanceInFormalMixer))*10 AttendanceInFormalMixer,
     sum(Convert(int,AttendanceInFbb))*10 AttendanceInFbb,
     sum(CASE WHEN GoodKarmaCredit <> 0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) GoodKarmaCredit,
     sum(CASE WHEN CupOfCofee <2 THEN CupOfCofee*5 ELSE 10 END) CupOfCofee,
     sum(CASE WHEN Convert(int,Business)<>0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) Business,
     sum(CASE WHEN Training<>0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) Training,
     sum(CASE WHEN Visitors<>0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) Visitors,

     convert(decimal(10,2),(sum(Convert(int,AttendanceInFormalMixer))*10 +
     sum(Convert(int,AttendanceInFbb))*10 +
     sum(CASE WHEN GoodKarmaCredit <> 0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) +
     sum(CASE WHEN CupOfCofee <2 THEN CupOfCofee*5 ELSE 10 END) +
     sum(CASE WHEN Convert(int,Business)<>0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) +
     sum(CASE WHEN Training<>0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) +
     sum(CASE WHEN Visitors<>0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) )*1.00/7)

     UserScore
    from [dbo].[MTS_MemberTracking] MtsTracking
    inner join MTS_Members mtsmem on MtsTracking.MemberId = mtsmem.MemberId
    where MtsTracking.MonthYear >= @monthYearFrom and  MtsTracking.MonthYear <= @monthYearTo

group by MtsTracking.MemberId
```